# Test my go app in a container launched by docker compose with Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a Golang app, that depends a FTP Server.

So, In docker compose, I build a FTP service and I refer to it into my tests.

So, in my docker-compose.yml I have:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mygoapp:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.local
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./volume:/go
      - ./test_files:/var/test_files

    networks:
      mygoapp_network:
    env_file:
      - test.env
    tty: true


  ftpd-server:
    container_name: ftpd-server
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "julien"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/www/julien"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      mygoapp_network:

networks:
  mygoapp_network:
    external: true
```

In my gitlab-ci.yml I have

```
variables:
  PACKAGE_PATH: /go/src/gitlab.com/xxx
  VOLUME_PATH: /var/test_files


stages:
  - test


# A hack to make Golang-in-Gitlab happy
.anchors:
  - &inject-gopath
      mkdir -p $(dirname ${PACKAGE_PATH})
      && ln -s ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} ${PACKAGE_PATH}
      && cd ${PACKAGE_PATH}

test:
  image: docker:18
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: test
  #  only:
  #    - production
  before_script:
    - touch test.env
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker network create mygoapp_network
    - mkdir -p volume/log

  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-local.yaml up --build -d
    - docker exec project-0_mygoapp_1 ls /var/test_files
    - docker exec project-0_mygoapp_1 echo $VOLUME_PATH
    - docker exec project-0_mygoapp_1 go test ./... -v
```

All my services are up

But when I run

```
- docker exec project-0_myapp_1 echo $VOLUME_PATH
```

I can see $VOLUME_PATH is equal to `/var/test_files`

but inside code, when I do:

```
os.Getenv("VOLUME_PATH")
```

variable is empty

Also, in local, with a docker exec, variable is OK.

I also tried to put Variables into `test` definition, but it still doesn' work

EDIT: The only way I could do it is setting environment vars in docker compose, but it is not so great

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? also I don't understand your approch, I don't see where you install golang.. is it already present within the Docker image? I am trying to get it work but not able yet

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of your script is predictable - all environment variables are being expanded when they are met (unless they are in single quotes). So, your line

```
docker exec project-0_myapp_1 echo $VOLUME_PATH
```

is expanded **before** being executed, and `$VOLUME_PATH` is taken from gitlab runner, not from container.

The only way I see to get this script printing environment variable from inside container is **putting script inside sh-file** and calling that file:

**doit.sh**

```
echo $VOLUME_PATH
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
docker exec project-0_myapp_1 doit.sh
```

Comment: ok, I understand, it explains why it doesn't work, but I still have the problem :)